# Python Flask variable update from DB

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that shows tabs on the /dashboard page. The name of each tab is a corresponding table found in the DB that flask is connected to. More tables get added and some removed auto.

I have a def called `get_locations()` that grabs all the table names and dumps then into a dict. This dict is pushed through to the HTML where the tabs are created and named accordingly. (with bootstrap)

When my Flask app starts I can see all tab names correctly that are present in the DB as tables.

**Problem:**
When a new table is created or removed I don't see the tabs being removed to created. (Updated)

**What I have done:**
I have a def that gets all the table names, this function is called on the /dashboard route. See below. However when I navigate to the /dashboard it doesn't update accordingly as I manipulate the DB in the back-end.

```
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
locations = []

def get_locations():
    global engine
    global insp
    global locations
    locations = []
    for i in insp.get_table_names():
        locations.append(str(i))
    return locations

@app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    i = 1
    locations = []
    return render_template("dashboard.html", TOPIC_DICT = TOPIC_DICT, locations=get_locations(), i=i)
```

When I refresh the page it still shows the old tables as the tabs, not the new tables added in the back-end. What is this madness!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try moving the definition of `insp` inside the function?

Comment: that worked thanks. add as a answer so I can accept it.